Card Management Ability Through API
Using the Banno API kit, I'm able to toggle different user abilities like RDA, Bill Pay and Transfers on/off but I cannot do it to the Card Management Ability. Using the call below to modify those abilities works for all of them but Card Management. I have tried both payment_card_management and paymentCardManagement (which is how it’s displayed when I do the Get User Abilities call) but neither turns it on/off. What am I missing?
{
  "zelle_enabled": "true",
  "rdc": false,
  "bill_pay": true,
  "paymentCardManagement": false,
  "external_transfer_inbound": false,
  "external_transfer_outbound": true
}


Assuming your are referencing the PUT /a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/abilities/update endpoint, the only supported abilities are the five listed in the schema:
  "zelle_enabled": "None",
  "rdc": true,
  "bill_pay": true,
  "external_transfer_inbound": true,
  "external_transfer_outbound": true


Yes, that's what I'm using. Is there any other call that can toggle the Card Management ability on/off? Thanks!

Not that I'm aware of at the moment, unfortunately!
